# у меня проблема, не проходит какой то пятый тест(сам тест не знаю), есть какие нибудь варианты в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
kol_zar, kol_pri = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
zar = [input() for i in range(kol_zar)]
zar2 = {j.lower(): j for j in zar}
pri = [input().lower() for j in range(kol_pri)]
pros = set()
for i in pri:
    str1 = ''
    str2 = ''
    for j in i:
        if j in '1234567890':
            str1 += j
    if int(str1) > 0:
        str2 = i[int(str1) - 1::int(str1)].lower()
    if str2 and str2 in zar2:
        pros.add(zar2[str2])
if pros:
    print('\n'.join(pros))
else:
    print('NO')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете уточнить что вам требуется,ибо не понятно в чем заключается проблема.

Comment: я так понимаю решение вашей проблемы вас более не интересует?

Answer (score 0):

я немного потестил ваш код и **вроде бы** выявил ошибку, т.к чужой код - потемки, то логику я полностью разбирать не стал, но:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

вот такую ошибку вытащить смог. Код должен не только правильно работать, но и **учитывать ошибки ввода**, в том числе и намеренные, в данном случае - `if int(str1) > 0` выдаст ошибку, если в слове вообще **нет цифр**, а значит он будет преобразовывать к `int` пустую строку, что не возможно.

```
if str1 and int(str1) > 0
```

должно исправить ситуацию